# Problems with path to resource folder

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have following build.properties in my eclipse plug-in

```
source.. = src/main/java,\
           src/main/resources
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
```

My plugin.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

 <extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
    <decorator
          adaptable="true"
          class="com.idc.xtext.shared.XtextFileDecorator"
          id="com.idc.xtext.shared.xtextFileDecorator"
          label="label"
          lightweight="false"
          location="REPLACE"
          objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
          state="true">
    </decorator>
 </extension>
</plugin>
               .
```

And following structure of the project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPGLT.jpg)

When I try to load the image with following code, I have null pointer exception.

```
private static void putInIconMap(
            HashMap<String, Image> pIconsMap, String pEnv, String pIconPath) {
        ImageDescriptor fromPlugin = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID,
                        pIconPath);
        try {

            Image createImage = fromPlugin.createImage();
            pIconsMap.put(pEnv, createImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

....

```
putInIconMap(dirsIconsMap, DEV, "icons/dev/Dirs_Dev_icon.png");
```

Look like some problem with the path to file. **I have check, all png files have actual name**
But why and how I can to fix it?
Regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

You must include the `resources` folder in the `bin.includes` section of your `build.properties`.

It is normal to put the `resources` folder at the top level of the project, not inside the `src` folder. In which case the `build.properties` would be:

```
source.. = src/main/java
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               resources/,
               .
```

And you would use a path like `resources/myimage.gif` in your code.

Comment: So I need to use resources/icons/dev/Config_Dev_icon.png instead of icons/dev/Config_Dev_icon.png, isn't it?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about exactly what your images are so I can't answer that. You could use `icons` as the top level folder if you want. The key thing is that they must be listed in the bin.includes.

Comment: Unfortunatly it's not working. Where can be problem?

Comment: You will have to show us a lot more detail about your current structure and code before we can say any more.